# mutable borrows in a loop

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime

## My code:

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    bytes: &'a mut [u8],
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn bar<'b>(&'b mut self) {
        self.bytes = &mut self.bytes[1..];
    }
}

fn baz<'a, 'b>(foo: &'b mut Foo<'a>) {
    println!("baz!");
    
    for _ in 0..3 {
        foo.bar();
    }
}
```

Also [here in a Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%23!%5Ballow(unused)%5D%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aany%3A%3AAny%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aio%3A%3ARead%3B%0A%0Astruct%20Foo%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bytes%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20%5Bu8%5D%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3C%27a%3E%20Foo%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20bar%3C%27b%3E(%26%27b%20mut%20self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.bytes%20%3D%20%26mut%20self.bytes%5B1..%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20baz%3C%27a%2C%20%27b%3E(foo%3A%20%26%27b%20mut%20Foo%3C%27a%3E)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22baz!%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20for%20_%20in%200..3%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foo.bar()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%7D).

This results in the following error traceback:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:12:27
   |
12 |         self.bytes = &mut self.bytes[1..];
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'b` as defined here...
  --> src/main.rs:11:12
   |
11 |     fn bar<'b>(&'b mut self) {
   |            ^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:12:27
   |
12 |         self.bytes = &mut self.bytes[1..];
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> src/main.rs:10:6
   |
10 | impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:12:22
   |
12 |         self.bytes = &mut self.bytes[1..];
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0495`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

## Goal

I'm looking to change the function signatures of `bar` / `baz` to get this to compile. My understanding was that I needed to specify lifetime bounds on `'a` & `'b` and it would work, but I get different errors for both `'b: 'a` and `'a: 'b` in either/both functions.

I've also looked through ~10 other "mutable borrow in loop" questions, but I don't understand the answers well enough to apply them to my problem, so even if this is a duplicate I'd appreciate an answer relevant to this toy example specifically.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The loop is irrelevant to your question - the errors are in `bar`.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo It is relevant, because without the loop you could make `bar()`'s signature `fn bar(&'a mut self)`, but with the loop you cannot (though even without loop, if you call it twice it will err).

Comment: Without deep looking, I'm afraid you cannot solve that with safe code only. This is the same reason why `std::slice::IterMut` cannot be implemented in safe code.

Comment: thank you both for your input! @ChayimFriedman I would rather write unsafe code than, e.g., give up and rewrite the signature to pass by value instead of by reference. **can you show me what an unsafe solution would look like?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@vikram2784's solution works, but can be expressed a bit more concisely by only replacing `bytes`, not the entire `Foo`:

```
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn bar(&mut self) {
        let tmp = &mut [][..];
        let bytes = std::mem::replace(&mut self.bytes, tmp);
        self.bytes = &mut bytes[1..];
    }
}
```

This pattern is also easier to use if `Foo` contains some additional fields that don't have obvious default values.

One thing to note about this kind of solution: If the `bytes[1..]` panics, the empty temporary will be left in place. Here, the only reason for a panic I can think of is `bytes` being empty, so it won't matter, but depending on the situation, you may get bitten by it.

Comment: this works great! I shortened it to use `bytes` & `tmp` directly w/o making them named variables, like so: `self.bytes = &mut core::mem::replace(&mut self.bytes, &mut [][..])[1..];`. but I appreciate the more verbose & legible example, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the borrow happens through `'b`. (`'b` and `'a` are disjoint). The compiler wants you to guarantee the reference `'b` needs to be atleast as long as `'a`. So we should look for a way where `'b` isn't involved when (re)borrowing the slice, as `'b` is considered to be valid only for the function call duration. There is no `return` or an "outgoing" lifetime from the call.

You can use the `std::mem::*` functions to achieve [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=869d23ac4f758bc34250d1d3d42d9373)

Comment: I understand the first two sentences of your explanation, but I don't understand the last two. can you explain that in more detail?